# LoaderManager не отключается после загрузки данных из БД?

Tags: android, утечка-памяти, android-loader

Приветствую! Имеется активность, в ней фрагмент. Фрагмент использует `LoaderManager` для асинхронной загрузки данных. Сделал простой пример для отработки: достаю информацию из БД и вставляю её в `TextView`. В мониторе памяти вижу такую картину :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, что загрузчик постоянно работает? разве он не должен загрузить данные и отключиться? Я отключал весь код в загрузчике и тогда потребление памяти прекращалось.

вот код

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.EViCo.revivemycar.DataBase;
import com.EViCo.revivemycar.R;
import com.EViCo.revivemycar.history.History;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Summary_fragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{
    DataBase db;
    TextView tv;

    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View summary_fragment = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false);

        db = new DataBase(getActivity());
        db.open();

        tv = summary_fragment.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(11, null, this);
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(11).forceLoad();


        return summary_fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bnd)
    {
        return new SummaryLoader(getActivity(), db, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
    {
        switch (loader.getId())
        {
            case 11:
                getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(11).forceLoad();
                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                tv.setText(cursor.getString(0));
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
    {

    }

    static class SummaryLoader extends CursorLoader
    {
        DataBase db;
        Cursor cursor;
        final int LoaderID;

        public SummaryLoader (Context context, DataBase db, int id)
        {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
            LoaderID = id;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground()
        {
            switch (LoaderID)
            {
                case 11: cursor = db.get_data();
                    break;
            }
            return cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я не вижу здесь никакой утечки

Comment: @pavlofff? то есть такая картина пилообразного выделения памяти это норма для лоадера?

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но `forceLoad()` вроде принудительно запускает загрузчик, не смотря на наличие уже загруженных данных. И тогда вызванный в `onLoadFinished` он зацикливает загрузку.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо за подсказку, я убрал `forceLoad()` и цикличная загрузка убралась, взамен добавил принудительное обновление в метод `onResume`, можете написать отдельным ответом?

Comment: утечка - это когда потребление памяти растет после работы сборщика мусора, у вас он вполне справляется с ситуацией, судя по графику. Насчет `forceLoad()` все верно - это команда заново получить данные и в `onLoadFinished()` эта команда абсолютно не уместна, так как колбэк срабатывает, когда данные получены - нет никакой надобности запрашивать их снова. Так же нет никакой надобности вызывать `forceLoad()` в `onResume()`, загрузчик сохранит курсор при поворотах устройства и прочих напастях - вызывать нужно только тогда, когда нужно реально обновить данные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `forceLoad()` принудительно запускает загрузчик, не смотря на наличие уже загруженных данных. Вызов его в `onLoadFinished` зацикливает работу загрузчика.